# Working with custom annotation in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, annotations, thymeleaf, data-annotations

I'm looking to create a custom validation annotation ( target = element.type ) for the entity class which checks if 2 fields under the class is the same. How can I implement that in thymeleaf? Please share example/code of the process, thank you!

Comment: what have you try that does not work ? what do you mean by "same"? same value? same name? same type?

Comment: By same I mean if 2 fields under an object equals in value. I've set up the custom annotation but not sure how to implement it in Thymeleaf, I've done the custom annotation implementation in thymeleaf when the annotation is for fields only